# Search Context is null error while building Selenium Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, frameworks, testng

I am trying to build a selenium framework using TestNG and PageObjectModel. I have created pageObject classes and Test Case classes but while running as "TestNG test" it is throwing the below error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkBrm.png)

I am also adding snippets of my code for better understanding:

BasePage Class : where I have defined a constructor that can be called inside all the classes under pageObjects
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcVDv.png)

Login Page Object Class: This class extends the BasePage class and hence will be able to invoke the constructor and also I have defined the locators and action methods
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aGi6.png)

Base Test Class: where I've defined the setup and teardown methods for launching the browser and closing it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tanps.png)

Login Test Case class: Here, I am sending the values to the fields defined in the Login Page Object class and clicking on login button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngM4l.png)

I tried putting implicit wait but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? It looks like you pass `null` driver to your page object.